# Nearest Neighbors algorithm by attribute importance

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributes, nearest-neighbor

I want to know what solutions are provided within Python libraries or Tensorflow libraries for finding nearest neighbor by attribute importance.
In KDTree library attributes are treated equally with same importance.

```
# KDTree  
import numpy as np  
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

# Neighbors and Neighbor
neighbors = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
                      [1, 2, 1, 2],
                      [2, 1, 1, 1],
                      [1, 0, 0, 0],
                      [1, 2, 0, 2],
                      [2, 2, 2, 2],
                      [1, 0, 0, 1]])

neighbor = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 1]])

tree = KDTree(neighbors, leaf_size=2)            
distance, ind = tree.query(neighbor, k=7)
```

In order to be explicit with what I am looking for I developed following halving interval algorithm to calculate nearest neighbor with decreasing importance of attribute from left to right. First attribute is the most important and last is the least important. 
https://github.com/itsergiu/Nearest-Neighbor-by-Attribute-Importance